# Custom docker image missing from Bluemix

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to deploy my custom Docker image following the CLI instructions.

I've pushed the image

`docker push registry.ng.bluemix.net/XXX/XXXXXX/centos-docker-broker:mytag`

And the output seems fine:

`The push refers to a repository [registry.ng.bluemix.net/XXX/XXXXXX/centos-docker-broker] (len: 1)
Sending image list
Pushing repository registry.ng.bluemix.net/XXX/XXXXXX/centos-docker-broker (1 tags)
Image ebdbe10e9b33 already pushed, skipping
Image 366219586e86 already pushed, skipping
Image fa5be2806d4c already pushed, skipping
Image 501f51238f9e already pushed, skipping
Image 1a895dd3954a already pushed, skipping
Image 755bf916afd3 already pushed, skipping
Image e94ed3d5b932 already pushed, skipping
Image 3fa79d064cb7 already pushed, skipping
Image 528af6b6dd27 already pushed, skipping
Image 7c1b7e04f409 already pushed, skipping
Image c50c1b0883b3 already pushed, skipping
Pushing tag for rev [c50c1b0883b3] on {https://registry.ng.bluemix.net/v1/repositories/XXX/XXXXXX/centos-docker-broker/tags/mytag}`

However, if I list the images, I don't see my custom image.  I only see the default ones.

`$ cf ic images
REPOSITORY                                        TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
registry.ng.bluemix.net/ibm-mobilefirst-starter   latest              5996bb6e51a1        8 days ago          770.4 MB
registry.ng.bluemix.net/ibm-node-strong-pm        latest              ef21e9d1656c        3 weeks ago         528.7 MB
registry.ng.bluemix.net/ibmliberty                latest              2209a9732f35        3 weeks ago         492.8 MB
registry.ng.bluemix.net/ibmnode                   latest              8f962f6afc9a        3 weeks ago         429 MB`

Where is my image?

Answer (score 1):

Seems I hadn't connect my local docker command to the external host, e.g.

```
    export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://containers-api.ng.bluemix.net:8443
    export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/xxx/.ice/certs/containers-api.ng.bluemix.net
    export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
```